# Export yfinance Balance Sheet Results To CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, yfinance

This code works great to obtain quarterly balance sheet results.  But I cannot seem to export *company_metrics* to a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import time

companies = ['AMZN','MSFT','FB']

company_metrics = {}
for company in companies:
        company_metrics[company] = {}
    
        company_info = yf.Ticker(company)
        company_metrics[company] = company_info.quarterly_balance_sheet

print(company_metrics)
```

I tried altering the above code with the following, but was not successful:

```
for company in companies:
    try:    
        company_metrics[company] = {}
        
        company_info = yf.Ticker(company)
        company_metrics[company] = company_info.quarterly_balance_sheet
    except:
        pass
        
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(company_metrics)
df.to_csv('stocksBS92222.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution it can work for you. I made an excel file containing the info in each sheet for different companies:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('multiple_stocks.xlsx') as writer:
   for i in companies:
        df = pd.DataFrame(company_metrics[i])
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i)
```

I think a CSV file containing the three companies is messy and `to_csv` do not allow multiple sheets in the same file, so excel is the way to go here. Let me know if it works.

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant!  Thank you!  Is it possible to have one sheet with just the latest quarter results?  So the results in column B would be AMZN, column C would be MSFT, column D would be FB, and all from the latest quarter reports (6/30/22 for these particular stocks)?

Comment: Hi @HTMLHelpMe, kindly please do not change the scope of the question, if this one solves your initial problem, please accept it. So for future people having same issue they will know how to approach it. You can open other question and I'll be happy to have a look. Regards.

Comment: Okay @Luis, marked as answered.  Excellent job.  Thank you again, very much appreciated.  If you think my question was clear, concise and showed effort on my part, please upvote it.

Comment: 100% Open a new one to have look, mate. Cheers!

Comment: Here is the new question.  Thank you again :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73822594/export-lastest-quarter-yfinance-balance-sheet-results-into-single-excel-workbook