# Export Lastest Quarter yfinance Balance Sheet Results Into Single Excel Workbook?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, yfinance

The code below is what I have so far, thanks to Luis from my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821933/export-yfinance-balance-sheet-results-to-csv).  The current code creates a separate worksheet for each ticker (and all quarters).  Current results are pictured below.

I would like to have one sheet with just the latest quarter results. So the results in column B would be AMZN, column C would be MSFT, column D would be FB, and all from the latest quarter reports (6/30/22 for these particular stocks).

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import time

companies = ['AMZN','MSFT','FB']

company_metrics = {}
for company in companies:
  
        company_metrics[company] = {}
        
        company_info = yf.Ticker(company)
        company_metrics[company] = company_info.quarterly_balance_sheet
        
with pd.ExcelWriter('multiple_stocks.xlsx') as writer:
   for i in companies:
        df = pd.DataFrame(company_metrics[i])
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
results = []

for i in companies:
        result = company_metrics[i].iloc[:, 0]
        results.append(result)
```

Then build the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(results).T
df.columns = companies
```

Lastly, build the excel:

```
df.to_excel('Output.xlsx')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Luis!  Superb work again :).  There is one small thing I noticed about these balance sheet results.  These companies have a different amount of balance sheet accounts (and rows in the output).  For example, when you look at your previous answer picture/results, FB's Long Term Investments is 6536000000, but in the picture above it is 27808000000 because the number of rows (balance sheet accounts) are different for these companies.  AMZN has 25 accounts (to row 26), MSFT has 26 accounts (to row 27), and FB has 22 accounts (to row 23).  Is there a quick fix like a lookup?  Thank you:)

Comment: Hola parcero!  Wondering if you could take a look at my other question that is using your code:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74226925/export-last-four-years-yfinance-balance-sheet-results-into-single-excel-workboo