# Export Last Four Years' yfinance Balance Sheet Results Into Single Excel Workbook?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

The code below exports the latest annual Balance Sheet data.  I trying to get all the available annual Balance Sheet data.  Four years is usually available (e.g., [GOOG](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/goog/balance-sheet?p=goog)).  Credit to Luis Alejandro Vargas Ramos, who basically created all this code from my other questions ([Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821933/export-yfinance-balance-sheet-results-to-csv) & [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73822594/export-lastest-quarter-yfinance-balance-sheet-results-into-single-excel-workbook)).

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import time

companies = ['GOOG','MSFT','AAPL']

company_metrics = {}
for company in companies:
  
        company_metrics[company] = {}
        
        company_info = yf.Ticker(company)
        company_metrics[company] = company_info.balance_sheet
        
results = []

for i in companies:
        result = company_metrics[i].iloc[:, 0]
        results.append(result)
#Then build the dataframe:

df = pd.DataFrame(results).T
df.columns = companies
#Lastly, build the excel:

df.to_excel('102722_5Yroutput.xlsx')
```

Code below pulls exactly what I want for a single stock ticker.  Picture below is what I am trying to export for multiple tickers (data is duplicated for illustrative purposes).

```
import yfinance as yf

stock = yf.Ticker("MSFT")

stock.balance_sheet
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using yahooquery, which is really fast instead of yfinance.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import time
from yahooquery import Ticker

symbols = ['fb', 'aapl', 'amzn', 'nflx', 'goog']

faang = Ticker(symbols)

faang.balance_sheet()

#Then build the dataframe:

df = pd.DataFrame(faang.balance_sheet())
#df = pd.DataFrame(faang.balance_sheet()).T
#use bottom line if you want to transpose the data

df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```